# Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser doesn't work with fairly large files in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

is there an alternative to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` method or a workaround? I am currently splitting the large files (>200 kb) into smaller files as a workaround. Anyone has a better idea or a robust alternative please?

Comment: 200kb is not large. What means "doesn't work"? Why you have these large files(say 200mb) at all? If you say that you can split them, why you don't use a database in the first place?

Comment: Tim, I agree the csv files aren't large. But, I keep getting "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'". Thinking again, I think the 3 header lines at the top of the files could be the problem although this doesn't happen with all the files despite having the same headers.

Comment: I finally found the issue which is an ambiguous "sep=;" that doesn't appear on excel but it does when I open the file in notepad. When I remove it manually, the file works.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue which is an ambiguous "sep=;" that doesn't appear on excel but it does when I open the same .csv file in notepad (Not sure why). Now, when I remove it manually, the file works.